# Accessing Admin data from Magento 2.1 Rest API

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, laravel-framework

I have integrated laravel 5.5 with magento 2.1

i-e: My magento installation works on http://magento.me
and my laravel part works on http://magento.me/laravel-panel

When so ever my customer is logged in on magento site and i hit API /rest/V1/customers/me
It returns me the customer data.

What could i do for getting admin data or know admin is logged via API .
same customer/me API responded like wise when admin is logged in

`{"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters":{"resources":"self"}}`

I have also applied admin authorization token with above request having admin level rights and All resources access.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass admin token in bearer. To get this token you need to consume below endpoint.

```
http://magento.me/rest/V1/integration/admin/token
```

and your request payload will look like below.

```
{
   "username" : "admin",
   "password" : "admin_password" 
}
```

You will get token in response just pass it authorization header like below.

```
$headers = array
   (
            'Authorization: Bearer=' . $token,
   );
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: ```$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin0101");

    $ch = curl_init("http://ariaflex.me/rest/V1/integration/customer/token");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

   
    $token = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));```

Magento is treating this account as customer instead of admin.

Comment: sorry my mistake, It will be admin in url instead of customer. I updated my answer.

Comment: By adding this as an admin i can have access token. and passing that to customers/me it responded me with this response
```"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters":{"resources":"self"}}``` Though my admin have all rights.

Comment: for customer/me api you need to send customer token

Comment: Cant get admin data with your suggested solution .

Comment: You will get admin token my solution then using this token. and you can use this token to access admin data. But this token can be used only for those endpoints which are defined as admin resources. for more info you should check webapi.xml of catalog module.